# How can I free base cystamine dihydrochloride?

Tags: organic-chemistry, extraction

I am using cystamine (free based) to conjugate to a phosphate group on an oligonucleotide. I tried several keyword searches on Google for neutralizing the dihydrochloride at the ends of the cystamine. But, I am unable to find a protocol. I had once found a procedure for the process, but I did not reference it and hence I am unable to find it again.

The procedure I followed was:

1. Dissolve the cystamine.2HCl in water.
2. Transfer to a separation funnel and add chloroform.
3. To this add 1N NaOH.
4. After shaking vigorously collect the chloroform layer which contains the cystamine.
5. Repeat extraction couple of times using more chloroform.
6. Pool fractions - dry with anhyd. MgSO4 - transfer to an RBF.
7. Evaporate on a RotaVap
8. Dry on schlenk line and store in an inert environment at 4 deg. C.

However, the extraction was not very efficient. Can anyone refer a protocol for the same?

Comment: Two things come to mind: cysteamine is water soluble so you may need to salt out your aq phase and also 1M NaOH may be strong enough to deprotonate the thiol. I would suggest adjusting the pH to close to 7 and adding salt before trying the organic extraction.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will attempt your method to see if there is any change in the result. But, I have done an NMR on the extracted "cystamine" and it shows a clean spectra with an intact disulfide bond.

Comment: Perhaps go with NaHCO3 sat

Comment: In that case focus on keeping your water volume down, use more concentrated base and salt the aq phase. Your product is most likely still in the aq phase

Comment: First off, I would always use methylene chloride ahead of chloroform, especially under basic conditions. You can 'pep' up your extraction by adding a small amount of a third solvent that dissolves in both water and your extracting solvent, and also dissolves your compound to some extent. Methanol, ethanol or THF normally spring to mind.

Comment: Yes I agree use CH2Cl2.

Comment: @Beerhunter Could you explain how the third solvent improves the extraction efficiency of the cystamine free base if it dissolves in both the aqueous phase and the extracting - chloroform phase?

Comment: @Beerhunter
Waylander and everyone else thanks for the answers. I think if I am able to follow the question in my previous comment, my query in the entirety would be clarified.  

Thank you

Comment: @Somdeb you said yourself the extraction wasn't efficient. Either switch extraction solvent, augment your extraction solvent or hamper your water solubility. I have no feel for the solubility without data. If polarity is an overriding factor, increase it for your organic phase. I don't mean add so much solvent you get one phase. Start with 5-10%.

Comment: If you found an answer useful in helping you, please mark it as accepted. If none of the answers helped you directly, you may post an answer yourself with the information. This is not a forum, so please don't edit the title with meta information. You can take the [tour] to find out more about this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the MgSO4 is absorbing your product. You may want to try another drying agent Try Na2SO4, zeolites, or azeotropic distillation (e.g. with benzene). Maybe NaOH will work, but it may react with cysteamine.

Comment: This question answered my query. So I am marking this as an answer. Hence marking my question as SOLVED. I am sorry but I don't require further answers to this question. Can any mod mark this question as CLOSED to answers? @Martin - マーチン♦

Answer (score 1):

Freebase cystamine can be recovered from the dihydrochloride salt in $95%$ or greater yield using the following method:

1. Dissolve the $\ce{cya.2HCl}$ in pure $\pu{10N}~\ce{NaOH}$. I typically did this with $\pu{10g}$ cyanuric acid at a time, but it will probably work at larger scales.
2. As the $\ce{cya.2HCl}$ reaches nearly full solubility (you may see a few small flakes still hanging on) the addition of a small amount more of the $\pu{10N}~\ce{NaOH}$ will turn the solution cloudy. This is the freebase cyanuric acid crashing out of solution. This typically happens at around $10-11~\mathrm{pH}$, and I believe it is the result of the high $\mathrm{pH}$ and high concentration of $\ce
   {NaCl}$ produced by the acid-base neutralization that salts the product out.
3. This cloudy solution can then be extracted with DCM. One extraction will get most of the cyanuric acid, but I typically do a couple more just to be sure. Doing this extraction in a separatory funnel tends to form a pretty thick emulsion - just wait it out.
4. Dry the DCM fractions over anhydrous salt, and reduce to a viscous, slightly opaque oil under vacuum.

As a note, be careful while doing the liquid-liquid extraction. You really don't want to spill a mixture of strong base and DCM all over yourself and your fume hood.